# is this correct: "Q:There are other options available A: like what?"

Tags: word-usage

What does "like what" mean? I'm asking because I'm not sure if this is correct.

And is this correct?

For example:

> Q: "There are other options available"

> A: "like what?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Like what" looks rude compared to the formal "There are other options available". I would express the meaning of "like what" in this way:

- A: There are other options available.
- B: ***Could you give me an example?*** / ***Which ones?*** / ***Such as?***